# Second and third condition if

Tags: conditionals

Why is the probablity of the second conditional *if* more than that of third conditional *if*? I read somewhere that the probablity of the 2nd conditional is 40% where the 3rd conditional is 0%. My question is, even though both conditions did not happen in the past nor did their result, why is it that the 2nd has more probablity than the 3rd?

> If I were rich, I would travel the world. (2nd con.)

> If I had studied hard, I would have passed the exam. (3rd)

Answer (score 2):

It is important that you distinguish the two major uses of what is commonly called the *second conditional* in English language teaching materials.

[The second conditional has the past tense in the if-clause (*protasis*) and *would + infinitive* in the main clause (*apodosis*)]

**Use 1**: To make a statement about the consequence of some possible future event or state.

A common example is: *If I won the lottery, I would quit my job*. This is presumably the context in which you have heard the 40% probability claim. In other words, the speaker thinks there is a 40% possibility of winning the lottery.

**Use 2**: To express a counterfactual - i.e a present state that does not exist.

For example, *If I knew the answer, I would tell you*. (But I don't know the answer.) There is no possibility being expressed here, in contrast to the supposed 40% possibility of winning the lottery.

Your sentence *If I were rich, I would travel the world* is an example of **Use 2** (*I am not rich*). So to stay with your terminology, there is an equal probability of *being rich* and *studying hard*, namely 0%.

Comment: +1 And to add that the 40% number is nonsense. With **Use 1** about the future, there is *no chance or a negligible chance* it will ever happen, which is why it's *unreal*. If it is 40% possible, then you have to use "first conditional" because a 40% chance is very real.

Comment: @gotube. Good point. I get that teachers need a clear and concise way to help their beginning learners differentiate between, for example, _If I win..._ and _If I won..._ . But using percentages to do so is not the right way in my opinion.